# How can I create more "create attachment" custom field - any idea?

Tags: custom-field, customization, uploads, media-library

```
define('MY_POST_TYPE', 'myslider');
  define('MY_POST_SLUG', 'myslider');

  function my_register_post_type () {
    $args = array (
        'label' => 'Gallery',
        'supports' => array( 'title', 'excerpt' ),
        'register_meta_box_cb' => 'my_meta_box_cb',
        'show_ui' => true,
        'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
        'query_var' => true,
        'order'    => 'ASC',
        'public' => true,
        'publicly_queryable' => false,
        'show_in_menu' => true, 
        'capability_type' => 'post',
        'has_archive' => true, 
        'hierarchical' => true,
        'menu_position' => null,
    );
    register_post_type( MY_POST_TYPE , $args );
  }
  add_action( 'init', 'my_register_post_type' );

  function my_meta_box_cb () {
    add_meta_box( MY_POST_TYPE . '_details' , 'Media Library', 'my_meta_box_details', MY_POST_TYPE, 'normal', 'high' );
  }

  function my_meta_box_details () {
    global $post;
    $post_ID = $post->ID; // global used by get_upload_iframe_src
    printf( "<iframe frameborder='0' src=' %s ' style='width: 100%%; height: 400px;'> </iframe>", get_upload_iframe_src('media') );
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working perfect :)

///////// Create attachment custom fields /////////////////////
function be_attachment_field_credit( $form_fields, $post ) {
    $form_fields['custom6'] = array(
        'label' => 'Custom6 Name',
        'input' => 'text',
        'value' => get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'custom6', true ),
        'helps' => 'custom6 Text',
    );

```
$form_fields['custom7'] = array(
    'label' => 'Custom7 URL',
    'input' => 'text',
    'value' => get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'custom7', true ),
    'helps' => 'custom7 link',
);


return $form_fields;
```

}

add_filter( 'attachment_fields_to_edit', 'be_attachment_field_credit', 10, 2 );

///////// attachment custom fields Saving /////////////////////

function be_attachment_field_credit_save( $post, $attachment ) {
    if( isset( $attachment['custom6'] ) )
        update_post_meta( $post['ID'], 'custom6', $attachment['custom6'] );

```
if( isset( $attachment['custom7'] ) )
    update_post_meta( $post['ID'], 'custom7', $attachment['custom7'] );


return $post;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I'm not so sure I understand your question but if I were to guess, this might help:

[`add_meta_box()` Examples - WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_meta_box#Examples)